Creating a custom tool for the forge viewer to only trigger the box-selection tool on control + drag events
I am trying to achieve the following:

Holding Control AND single clicking should allow for multi-select (cumulative selection)

Holding Control THEN dragging the mouse should trigger the box-selection tool


The problem I am facing is that if I want to allow the default implementation (cummulative selection) when the mouse is not being dragged I must stop the propagation of the event after a control key is pressed.
Because a user would press control before starting to drag the mouse I don't currently see any way of only enabling box-selection once dragging begins. Is this something possible? Am I looking in the completely wrong direction? Or have I hit a dead-end?
My implementation:

/**
 * Custom forge viewer tool to restrict box-selection to ctrl key + mouse drag action
 * @param viewer Reference to the forge viewer instance
 * @see {@link https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/custom-tools-forge-viewer|Forge Documentation}
 */
export const getCustomBoxSelectionTool = (viewer) => {
  if (!viewer?.toolController) return null;

  let isDragging = false;

  const boxSelectionTool: NonNullable<CustomToolType> = {
    active: false,
    getName: () => 'custom-box-selection,
    getNames: () => ['custom-box-selection'],
    activate: async () => {
      boxSelectionTool.active = true;
    },
    deactivate: () => {
      boxSelectionTool.active = false;
    },
    getPriority: () => 1, // Set priority in the tool chain

    handleKeyDown: (event, _key) => {
      if (!event.ctrlKey) return false;

      if (isDragging) {
        viewer.toolController.activateTool('box-selection');
        return false; // Allow propagation
      } else {
        // Prevent default box-selection behaviour
        viewer.toolController.deactivateTool('box-selection');
        // !! This prevents the event propagating to the mousemove event (as dragging would happen after pressing control)
        return true; // Stop propagation
      }
    },

    handleKeyUp: (event, _key) => {
      if (event.ctrlKey) {
        viewer.toolController.deactivateTool('box-selection');
      }

      return false; // Allow propagation
    },

    handleButtonDown: (_event, button) => {
      // Check for left click (0 = left, 1 = middle, 2 = right)
      if (button === 0) {
        isDragging = true;
      }
      return false; // Allow propagation
    },

    handleButtonUp: (_event, button) => {
      // Check for left click (0 = left, 1 = middle, 2 = right)
      if (button === 0) {
        isDragging = false;
      }

      viewer.toolController.deactivateTool('box-selection');
      return false; // Allow propagation
    },

    handleMouseMove: event => {
      if (event.ctrlKey && isDragging) {
        viewer.toolController.activateTool('box-selection');
      }

      return false; // Allow propagation
    }
  };

  return boxSelectionTool;
};

Due to stopping the propagation in the the handleKeyDown function, the flow never makes it into the handleMouseMove function. I've tried using different combination of handlers including the handleSingleClick but I never end up with the desired end result.

That's a bit tricky.  But you are going down the right path.
Essentially you have a custom controller, that acts as a proxy to the other two controllers (Box and multi) and you are taking the custom actions and using the Box and Multi APIs to trigger the UX behavior you want.
I'm not completely sure which event is missing, but you can look at the unminified version of the extensions source code of Box and Multi extensions, to figure it out.
Does that help ?
